# Assuming $G=(V(G),E(G))$ is a graph what does $\Delta(G)$ mean?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, matroids

Perhaps someone is kind enough to explain to me the meaning of this mathematical symbol, that I found in Discrete Mathematics (Matroid Theory)?

Let $G=(V(G),E(G))$ be a graph. What does

$$\Delta(G)$$

mean? From the context I can determine, that $\Delta(G)$ computes an integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$. But I don't know for what $k$ stands.

The exercise is:
Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $G$ be a graph. Define
$$\mathcal{F}_{G}:=\{F\subset E(G): \Delta((V(G),F))\leq k\}$$
etc.

Comment: Could you give the source? I can think of at least two things (the maximum degree, or the Laplacian).

Comment: Someone might know this offhand (I don't), but perhaps you could give us some context?

Comment: I'll add the whole exercise in a sec.

Comment: Makes sense it's max-degree; lowercase delta is degree of a given vertex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the [maximum degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29).